# Set Output type of the From/TryFrom trait to Option<T>

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to return an `Option` from the `From` trait:

```rust
struct Tmp(i32);

impl From<i32> for Option<Tmp> {
    type Output = Option<Self>;

    fn from(num: i32) -> Option<Self> {
        Some(Self(num))
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't have the `Output` type as a member. I'm getting this error message:

```
error[E0437]: type `Output` is not a member of trait `From`
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     type Output = Option<Self>;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `From`

error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | impl From<i32> for Option<Tmp> {
  | ^^^^^---------^^^^^-----------
  | |    |             |
  | |    |             `Option` is not defined in the current crate
  | |    `i32` is not defined in the current crate
  | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
  |
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Is there a trait for this? Do I have to implement a function on my own for that, like this:

```rust
struct Tmp(i32);

impl Tmp {
    pub fn from_i32(num: i32) -> Option<Self> {
        Some(Tmp(num))
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want `TryFrom` instead of `From`.

Comment: `TryFrom::try_from` returns a `Result`, but you can use `.ok()` to turn that into an `Option` when you use it.

Comment: But implementing it as an inherent method is also completely valid.

Comment: Your first example doesn’t even make sense: `Self` is `Option<Tmp>`, so the expected return type is `Option<Option<Tmp>>` but you’re returning an `Option<{integer}>`?!  The error message then quotes code that doesn’t appear in the snippet.

Comment: @eggyal yes you're right, sorry about that! I forgot to update the code example as well. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: @PeterHall Those two options which you mentioned are pretty good suggestions, could you write an answer please which includes both options so I can tick that quetsion as answered? (I decided to write an inherent method for that now :))

Comment: Okay, but now you're returning `Some(Self(num))` where `Self` is still `Option<Tmp>`—and since `Option` is not a newtype-struct, that's still nonsense.  Perhaps you meant to return `Some(Some(Tmp(num)))` or (more likely) perhaps you meant for `Self` to be `Tmp`?

Comment: But if I write `impl From<i32> for Tmp {` than rust expects from the `from` trait-function to return a `Tmp` struct, which is not what I want, I want to return an `Option<Tmp>` not `Tmp`.

Comment: Except you're always returning `Some` so what's the point in the `Option` at all?  Why not just return a `Tmp`?

Comment: This is just an example, it's different in my "real" code.